# How to cast a generic type into an actual type in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, typeinfo

Consider the following code

```
procedure TMyClass.SetParam<T>(Name: string; Value: T);
begin
  if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(string)) then
  begin
    FHashTable.AddString(Name, (Value as string));
  end
  else if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer)) then
  begin
    FHashTable.AddInteger(Name, (Value as Integer));
  end
......
```

I want to have a generic procedure that gets a generic value of type T and according to the actual type of T insert the value to an hashtable.

The compiler won't let me do this cast, also won't let me do something like Integer(Value).

Can someone please explain how should i implement the above?

Comment: If you have separate code for each type that `T` may be, then why don't you have separate methods instead? E.g. `SetStringParam`, `SetIntegerParam`, etc.? For what you are doing, it makes no sense whatsoever to use a generic `SetParam<T>` method.

Comment: Isn't this what TValue was invented for. Your code doesn't look like it's really very generic.

Comment: FWIW, instead of `SetIntegerParam`, etc, you can also have several overloaded procedures, all with the name `SetParam`. They don't have to be generic.

Comment: Almost certainly your current design is a mistake. What problem are you attempting to solve? And why do you feel that you have to abandon compile time type safety?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the problem is that I am also maintaining code in C# so the code in both platforms should be the same. I will probably give up on the generic implementation because i agree it makes no sense here, will take Rudy's advise and just overload these procedures.

Comment: Be aware that having a generic class or method that then specifically handles specific types, such as the way you're attempting to do, is usually a strong code smell.

Comment: Probably worth fixing the C# code too!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can do this type of thing easily with classes, it is not so easy with other types, like integers, strings and enums. Although they work with generics to an extent, they are not great. On the other hand, in this case you don't need to.

Because generics are *so* useful there is a great temptation to rush into generics when they are not really needed (I know I have fallen into that trap more than once). All you need here is overloaded functions as is shown below.

```
unit UnitTest1;

interface

type
  THashTable = class
    procedure AddString( const pName : string; pValue : string ); virtual; abstract;  // dummy for illustration only
    procedure AddInt( const pName : string; const pInt : integer ); virtual; abstract;  // dummy for illustration only
  end;

  TMyClass = class
  private
    FHashTable : THashTable;
  public
    procedure TestString;
    procedure TestInt;

    procedure SetParam( const pName : string; const pValue : string ); overload;
    procedure SetParam( const pName : string; const pValue : integer ); overload;

  end;

implementation

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.SetParam(const pName, pValue: string);
begin
  FHashTable.AddString( pName, pValue );
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetParam(const pName: string; const pValue: integer);
begin
  FHashTable.AddInt( pName, pValue );
end;

procedure TMyClass.TestInt;
begin
  SetParam( 'Int', 4 );
end;

procedure TMyClass.TestString;
begin
  SetParam( 'Int', 'Fred' );
end;

end.
```

I have created a dummy class THashTable for the purposes of illustration only and I have not created FHashTable. This is simply to illustrate the principles. I know the code will not run as it stands, but it will compile.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i did as advised earlier.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.SetParam<T>(Name: string; Value: T);
begin
  if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(string)) then
  begin
    FHashTable.AddString(Name, PString(@Value)^);
  end
  else if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer)) then
  begin
    FHashTable.AddInteger(Name, PInteger(@Value)^);
  end
......
```

Or this:

```
uses
  System.Rtti;

procedure TMyClass.SetParam<T>(Name: string; Value: T);
var
  LValue: TValue;
begin
  LValue := TValue.From<T>(Value);
  if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(string)) then
  begin
    FHashTable.AddString(Name, LValue.AsString);
  end
  else if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer)) then
  begin
    FHashTable.AddInteger(Name, LValue.AsInteger);
  end
......
```